# Partial Application of App Middleware with Slim PHP Framework

Tags: php, slim

I'm writing a REST API with Slim and I want some parts of my API require a login and some to be publicly available. For authentication, I'm using the StrongAuth middleware from Slim Extras.

Unfortunately, StrongAuth kills the request if authentication isn't provided and is an app middleware (which seem to be all or nothing), so I've been building my API entirely secured by StrongAuth, allowing public resources to be accessed by a dummy login.

However, this isn't ideal; I'd like to just have unsecured resources. I tried running two apps in the same file, but one of them always throws a 404 error, which is obviously unacceptable.

Does anyone know a way to apply an app-level middleware to only some routes in Slim, or how to run multiple Slim apps in the same file without issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slim middlewares all implement the public method call(), you could try to add it to your desired route this way. For that you need to get an instance of your middleware ($auth) without using it as a middleware.

```
$app->get('/yourSecuredRoute', array($auth,'call'), function() use($app){
        $app->render('index.html');
});
```

Not sure if it works, and even if it does, it's tricky and there should be a better way such as writing your own route-level middleware.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not much of a PHP guy, and this wasn't in the documentation.

Comment: Nope, if strongAuth y app level and you use it as route middleware it will run twice in that route... I think... @john did it worked as you expected ?

Comment: If I remember right, you should not add it as an app-level middle ware but just for the specific route.